# Power Automate "Send an Email (V2) doesn't seem to be supporting UTF-8 characters, anything to do?

Tags: power-automate, adaptive-cards, power-platform

I created Power Automate flow which includes "Send an Email (V2) action step for sending an email which includes adaptive card. The problem is that every scandic character like "ä, ö, å" are shown as "?" in the email.

This is the code inside "Send an Email (V2) step:

```html
<p>message below</p>

<script type="application/adaptivecard+json" charset="UTF-8">
  @{outputs('Compose_2')}
</script>
```

Compose_2 has json card in it which doesn't have any problems with special characters.

Is there anything I could do or is this something that MS has to fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So... I think I somehow solved this by pure accident.

I added word with "ä" character in the html before the `"<script type="application/adaptivecard+json" charset="UTF-8">`"

like this:

```html
<p>Viestiä on alapuolella</p>

<script type="application/adaptivecard+json" charset="UTF-8">
  @{outputs('Compose')}
</script>
```

and now it works perfectly. Could this be some kind of bug that if special characters are not used before the script, it won't use the UTF-8?